# Why would a programming question on a new Java version be off topic?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I had a question, re: *[New Features in Java 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29472666/what-are-the-new-features-coming-in-java-10)*, that I was curious about and was surprised to see it closed for being "off topic".

Java is a programming language and there are lots of questions about its features by version, so what is the reasoning here?

I would have thought maybe it's too new still and that was the reason, but still some features are being talked about. If I don't understand what the problem was, I can't really edit it to make it fit better and possibly get it reopened.

Comment: In a couple years, when eveyone is upgrading to Java 17, how will your question/answers be useful?

Comment: Are you going to close all the questions related to Java 4 and 5 this year?  There is company in St. Louis that is still on Java 1.2 and Corba.  Legacy code still exists.

Comment: The title is awful, but the real question can be interesting if you would have been able to ask about how your current java code will be different if the primitive types are gone. Instead you're asking for more information, which is off-topic because you ask for an off-site resource. In that sense the question is not useful.

Comment: Okay, that was the real intent off the first question, so thanks for clarifying.  I don't know if I can edit it, but I'll try.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question is a list question. You're asking for a list of things. And while it is technically a list of objective facts which are finite, it has some of the problems of a [shopping list question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad):

For example, how do you know if a particular answer is correct? It would have to list *every* change. And how can you know if it truly does list every change? If you knew, you wouldn't need to ask the question.

This inevitably means that the only way a reader can get the "right" answer is to read *all* of the answers. Which means that there is no one answer; there are just pieces of the answer scattered across multiple posts.

Also, such a question suggests that the aggregation of answers fully answers the question. But there's no way to ensure that; even with 10 answers, some things may be missed.

Ultimately, Stack Overflow is not the best place for that kind of question.